# Inheritance in Django model vs template usage

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am quite new to Django framework.
I have a question(problem) to solve.

I have model design:
Class "Pet" is abstract class.
Three classes inherit from Pet:
 - Dog
 - Cat
 - Bird

Also there is a class Registration that has foreign key linked to Pet that can be any of those three kind of Pets. Could you help me what is the best practice to design a database structure like this and how to deal with it using Django template framework?

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement something called **Polymorphic Associations**.

Maybe

1. you should take a look at [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#), or
2. If you are comfortable with making some changes in the Registration Model. Just add a column denoting what key is stored in which table, so you will have a column with Dog, Cat or Bird and another column with their id (Not as a Foreign Key but as a simple integer). In this way, once you create efficient functions for storing and fetching values, you won't really have to look at it again. (It worked for me)

Comment: Thank you! But then if I would like to add new kind of animal like rabbit I will have to make a lot of changes in DB won't I ?

Comment: Not really, lets say you have 3 tables and in Registration Model you have many instances divided among those three keys, (Dog, Cat, Bird). You do have Different Model for each of them as well.
Now suppose you have Bats too! you will simply add Bats in the new instances, and since you are adding a new animal, I suppose you will be adding new model for it anyways

Comment: Also, if there is some way that you can merge all the tables directly
I should say that you do that, It will help you add and remove animals easily.
Or just include django-polymorphic in your project